# Any Plugin or Addson To not Use CSS Browsers Prefixes

Tags: jquery, css

I already Google this but couldn't find any thing! CAn you please let me know if there is a trick/Library to not repeat the CSS extentions for browsewrs? instead of using `-webkit-` and `-moz-` and `-o-`?

```
  -webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; 
  -moz-animation:    NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; 
  -o-animation:      NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; 
  animation:         NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite;
```

I used to see a solution by a girl on the web but I couldn't find it now!

Comment: Using JS would be a bad idea for this as it's processed a lot later in the rendering cycle compared to JS, so there would be a very noticeable FOUC. I think a CSS pre-processor would suit your needs the best as you can define functions to auto-generate the needed vendor prefixes for you (amongst many other very useful features). Check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: Those are called prefixes.  https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an autoprefixer! You can use it with grunt, webpack, or gulp!

https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer